# How to addEventListener that takes effect on the state after a paste (instead of right before it)?

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener, copy-paste

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="some text">

<button id='coolButton' onclick="coolFunction()">Click me</button>

<br><br>
<span>Entered:</span>
<span id="enteredBox"></span>

<script>

//display whatever is in the textbox in a text span below it 
function coolFunction() {
  word = document.getElementById("myText").value; 
  document.getElementById("enteredBox").innerHTML = word;
}

//trigger coolFunction() whenever something is pasted into the text box
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('paste', () => {
  document.getElementById("coolButton").click();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the "Click me" button, whatever is currently in the textbox is properly displayed below it.
I want this same behavior to happen automatically when the user pastes into the box. So I add an event listener to the text box listening for a paste.

However, the code inside this paste listener works on what was in the text box before the paste. i.e. if there is "a" in the text box, and the user pastes a "b" into the box, only "a" (and not "ab") will be displayed below.

How do I make the event listener's code take effect after the paste is complete?

I've tried things like forcing it to wait a couple seconds, or displaying in a separate element, but the paste function code always reads what was in the box before the paste instead of after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make the event listener's code take effect after the paste is complete?

You can use [.getData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData):

> The DataTransfer.getData() method retrieves drag data (as a DOMString)
> for the specified type. If the drag operation does not include data,
> this method returns an empty string.

In order to get the clipboard data you need to use the event parameter to your paste event handler as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback).

The snippet:

```js
function coolFunction() {
  word = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("enteredBox").innerHTML = word;
}

document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('paste', function(e)  {
  // get the data from the clipboard.....
  var txt = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
  
  // use the data
  document.getElementById("enteredBox").innerHTML = txt;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="some text">

<button id='coolButton' onclick="coolFunction()">Click me</button>

<br><br>
<span>Entered:</span>
<span id="enteredBox"></span>
```

Or, if you need to get the data after the paste action compteted, you can delay the click event with a [.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). In this case your  code:

```
document.getElementById("coolButton").click();
```

becomes:

```
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("coolButton").click(), 10)
```

The snippet:

```js
//display whatever is in the textbox in a text span below it
function coolFunction() {
    word = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("enteredBox").innerHTML = word;
}

//trigger coolFunction() whenever something is pasted into the text box
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('paste', (e)  =>
   setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("coolButton").click(), 10)
);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="some text">

<button id='coolButton' onclick="coolFunction()">Click me</button>

<br><br>
<span>Entered:</span>
<span id="enteredBox"></span>
```

A last solution can avoid at all the button and it can be based on [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

The snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('input', function(e)  {
    word = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("enteredBox").innerHTML = word;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="some text">



<br><br>
<span>Entered:</span>
<span id="enteredBox"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both of these work.  Do you mind explaining the first method involving reading directly from the clipboard a bit more? I don't understand why the `e` variable would contain clipboard information. I thought `e` always has error information. The Mozilla docs are a bit confusing as well, because there is a separate page on the Clipboard API which has an identically named function...

Comment: @JamesRonald  The **e** variable in the event listener is the event. I updated the answer adding a reference to the documentation. I hope it will help you. Thanks